# Iterating equations in R

Tags: r, loops, iteration

I have the equation: X(n+1) = R * x * (1 - x), for some initial x value and constant R value.

I want to iterate this equation for a set number of iterations, starting with the initial value and then using the output as the subsequent input.

I have been exploring many looping options in R but I am still not able to understand how to tell R what I need (I am an R noob!). Every looping function I look at assumes that I have some prior vector/list to apply a function to, where I would like each iteration to use the previous answer as input.

Using a for loop, I just receive 5 iterations of 0.625, for example:

```
initial.x <- 0.5
NofIterations <- 1:5
R = 2.5
nofiterations <- 5

for (i in 1:nofiterations) {
y <- R * initial.x * (1 - initial.x)
print(y)
  }
```

Thanks in advance for any advice! I understand this is just easy, but normal troubleshooting seems not to be working for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Are you just looking at how to create a vector and index into it:

```
> R <- 2.5
> nofiterations <- 5
> x = rep(NA,nofiterations)
> x[1]=0.5
> for (i in 1:nofiterations) {
+ x[i+1] = R * x[i] * (1-x[i])
+ }
> x
[1] 0.5000000 0.6250000 0.5859375 0.6065369 0.5966247 0.6016591
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to do ?

```
x <- 0.5
R <- 2.5
nofiterations <- 5

for (i in 1:nofiterations) {
  x <- R * x * (1 - x)
  print(x)
}
```

Comment: No, since this does not use the first iteration's result as the next iteration's input. Using this code just results in the same result every time, since there is only one x input every time

Comment: Oops, I did run your code, but with a mistake in it (the same mistake I put in my original question, actually!). I've run it again, and it works fine. Thanks